# Open random script files from folder using Applescript

Tags: random, scripting, applescript

```
Set theFolder to (Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:Dsource)

Set rnd to (random number from 1 to 3)

Set myScript to load script file (rnd) of theFolder

Run script myScript
```

This is the script I am attempting to use to open random script files from a folder and execute them.  I have written 3 or 4 different types of scripts to try and do this but none seem to work.  Can someone point out the error or show me how to do this.  Thanks

Comment: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/03/apple-script-random-number-generator.html and https://discussions.apple.com/message/11469162#11469162

Comment: BTW also check out the "Library Window" in AppleScript-Editor (CMD-SHIFT-L). You can add apps here to have fast access to it's scripting dictionary (double-click shows it). The scripting dictionary shows the whole command set offered by an "addition" or an application. Check out "StandardAdditions" which contains commands like "beep", ”choose color","load script" or "display dialog" and many more. Put  "script" into the Search field to see all commands that contain "script" in it's name (here I have 5 commands).

Comment: Found the script library and apples applescript reference guide.  Thanks though…learning slowly…what I accomplished today…and I'm delighted…would probably seem like childs play to all y'all.  you can do more with applescript but it would have been delightful to a 38 yr old if they had structured more like BASIC. :) They are very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==> 1. make a folder on your desktop named "Dsource"

==> 2. create a script and name it "1". The script shall contain `display dialog "Script 1"` so when you start it it shows the script-number. Save/put it into the Dsource folder and repeat that (but change the number in the display dialog) until you have 3 scripts. Note: often the file name extension is hidden in Finder but such scripts have the extension ".scpt".

If above things are given this should work:

```
run script (load script file (((path to desktop) as text) & "Dsource:" & (((random number from 1 to 3) as text) & ".scpt")))
```

ADDITION:
Longer version which does the same but does it step by step:

```
try

    set pathToMyFolderOnDesktop to (path to desktop as text) & "Dsource:" as alias

    set rnd to (random number from 1 to 3)

    set rndFileName to (rnd as text) & ".scpt"

    set FullPath to pathToMyFolderOnDesktop & rndFileName as text

    set myScript to load script (FullPath as alias)
    run script myScript


on error the error_message number the error_number

    display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    return

end try
```

This also displays an error if - for example - the folder isn't there (-43).

Comment: I don't understand your script as I am "a noob".  I learn by seeing actual scripts as I'm just learning. But thanks for trying to help DigiMonk.

Comment: the good thing is: it does the job. "run script" uses the result of "load script" and the rest is simple scripting to compose the file path with random number between 1-3 and the correct name-ending (which you forgot in your script) .

Comment: so your script would be run script(load script file(((Macintosh HD:users:jr:Desktop) & "Dsource:" (((random number from 1 to 3)) & ".scpt")))

Comment: and name the scripts with numbers

Comment: Tips: ctrl-click into a script to see code-snippets. Activate the script assistant in AppleScript-Editor's preferences (does code-completion with ESCape key).

Comment: @Jody OK I Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Hallelujah!  That worked.  It's choosing random files from the folder and giving me the filenames in the dialog box. Go DigiMonk

Comment: How do you get reputation points if it want let me vote for you?

Comment: I can not thank the both of you enough as I have been trying to figure this out for a solid week and I mean somedays it was from the time i got up till the 2 and 3 in the morning.

Comment: Enjoy the feeling of success :) glad we could help. (accepted answers gives 15 points, one upvote gives 10)

Answer (score 0):

#### Strings aren't folders in Applescript

You are trying to access files using a string. `"Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:Dsource"` is not a folder until you make it one. So, this line

```
Set myScript to load script file (rnd) of theFolder
```

is getting the `rnd` character from the string (i.e. `M` if `rnd` is 1) and trying to do `load script` on it.

To make a string into something that Applescript recognizes as a folder, you can add `alias` to the front so it's `alias "Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:Dsource"`

#### You need to target a file

Assuming, you could get all the files of a folder with the following line, your logic is still a little off.

```
Set myScript to load script file (rnd) of theFolder
```

This line would be targeting a file *named* `rnd`. Not the `rnd` file of the folder. In other words, this line evaluates to

```
Set myScript to load script file "Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:Dsource:1"
```

#### The easy way to do it

Applescript provides the `some` command, which allows you to choose a random item from a list

```
some item of {1, 2, 3}
--> 2
some item of {1, 2, 3}
--> 1
```

So, gather your existing script files in a list, and choose a random one from that list.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set scriptFiles to files of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:jr:Desktop:Dsource:" whose kind is "Compiled OSA Script"
end tell

if (count scriptFiles) > 0
    set myScript to load script (some item of scriptFiles)
    run myScript
else
    display dialog "No script files were found."
end if
```

Comment: I had already tried variations on the some command and will work when I use "Finder" but "Finder" always opens the file with a window.  I tried your script as well and get the following error:

Comment: I had already tried variations on the some command and will work when I use "Finder" but "Finder" always opens the file with a window.  I tried your script as well and get the following error:error "Can’t get some item of {}." number -1728 from some item of {} and it highlights "load script (some item of scriptFiles)"  :(

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Jody, You don't have any script files in your source folder. I have updated the code to do error checking for this case.

Comment: As I don't have enough reputation on here to post pics..which I tried to do with my source folder and the files that are in them…all I can say is yes, I have 4 .scpt files in my source folder.

Comment: Would it matter that they are set to read and write?  Should they be set to read only?